# ASP.Net MVC Routing URL QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url, routes, query-string

Is there a way to link to another View that displays search results without having to use a querystring?  For example, I know that I can do the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(string txtOrderNumber)
{
    return RedirectToAction("OrderLookup", new { controller = "Report", id = txtOrderNumber });            
}
```

But, let's say that I only want to use a hyperlink (a hyperlink with the Order Number) and not a form post.  How can I route to the result View without using a querystring?  many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the txtOrderNumber argument to id. Then it will get picked up by the default route. Alternately, introduce a new route with a value called txtOrderNumber in the same place as the id value in the default route, and constrain it to respond to only this controller.

Comment: Thanks Craig.  But wouldn't that still show up in the route?  Basically I dont want the order number to show up anywhere in the URL.

Comment: If you don't want the search string to come from the URL, a query string parameter, or a form field, where, exactly, do you expect to get it from?

Comment: I guess that was the question.  For instance, with WebForms you could use CommandArguement, etc.  I just wanted to make sure I wasnt missing something.  Im converting a WebForm app that used linkbuttons and didnt show the values in the URL.  But it sounds like that may not be possible with MVC.

Comment: Well, MVC can use the same mechanisms that WebForms uses. WebForms uses a form field here, under the hood. You can do the same if you want (and already have, from the looks of the question). You can POST from a link (instead of a button) with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

With webforms the command argument is passed by making a post and the value is stored in a control (i believe is stored in a hidden field or the viewstate which is also a hidden field), but the page does post back.

If you don't want to make a post and don't use a querystring the only solution i can come up with is for you to do a post to the same page, capture the id store it in TempData and then do a RedirectToAction. In the controller simply use the TempData value stored from the previous page.

This still generates a post, but if the user refreshes the page they will not see the "Resend Data" message.